# Image refreshing with setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout, setinterval

I have 4 div´s each contains an image item  and a select list of 4 div-id. I want to refresh the images simultaneously by changing the source of each image every 2 seconds.

I'm using `setInterval()` for each image and the problem is when I must stop all the timers at the same time.

Should I make a timer variable per div/img?

```
$(.div-id option:selected).each(function(){
   var timer = setInterval(function(){
       $(.div-id img).attr("src", "new-source-path");
   },2000);
});
```

How can I stop all the active timers at once without stopping every timer Id?

Is there any solution with `setTimeout()` or any plugin to do that?

Comment: Why not just store all the IDs in an array, loop the array and stop the timeout via a function? (also, you're missing quotes in your jQuery selectors)

Comment: Have you tried running this code?

Comment: $(.div-id img) is not a valid selector. Try: $(".div-id img")

Comment: i will try with the Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd opt for a single timer that loops through all images. Then when the timer isn't needed anymore I can just discard the single timer.

```
var timer = setInterval(swapImages, 2000);
function swapImages() {
    $(.div-id option:selected).each(function(){
        $(.div-id img).attr("src", "new-source-path"); 
    });
}

// some time later
clearInterval(timer);
```

PS. I assume that your code is some pseudo code so I copied your namings

Answer (score 0):

The end solution

```
function swapImages() {
        $(".div-id-list option:selected").each(function () {
            var url = "new-source-path";
            $("#div-id img").attr("src", url);
        });
    }

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}


$(".div-id-list").on("change", function () {
    stopTimer();
    timer = setInterval(swapImages, 2000);
});
```

Thanks to donnywals !